# How to set that people on one list will not be able to see posts on my timeline from people of a different list

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline, facebook-tags

Is there a way to set that people in a specific list will not be able to see posts that people from another list posted on my timeline?

For instance, to set it so that my ex-boss will not be able to see posts that my mom posts on my timeline, but will be able to see other posts.

Answer (score 1):

**There isn't a way to do that**. 
One can only choose who can see what **ANY** other people post on your timeline. If your family members post personal things or things you don't want there, you may want to suggest that they send you private messages instead or you may want to get creative and start a Group for your family to have family discussions there. If you make it Closed or Secret, no one else will be able to read what is posted in the group. Just don't make it an Open group.
(Sheri Hurt)